# Built in *safe* way to move out of Vec<T>?

Tags: rust

I've been looking over the documentation, and so far I haven't seen a built in function to safely move an item out of a `Vec`.

`Vec::get` exists, but that just borrows. `Vec::remove` exists, and while that does move out of the vector, it also panics if the index is out of range. So, I have two questions:

1. What is the intended/good way to move an item from a vector?
2. `remove(&mut self, index: usize) -> T` panics if out of range. What might be the reason for panicking? Why isn't it implemented like `remove(&mut self, index: usize) -> Option<T>`?

Comment: In my experience it's pretty rare to have indices into a vector where you don't know if they're valid. Panicking fits that common case, where an invalid index represents a bug. For the uncommon case you can simply validate the index before using it.

Answer (score 23):

If you say *safe* in a Rust context, we think of memory safety. `.remove(i)` is certainly safe in regular Rust terms, just to clarify. Calling `panic!()` is *safe*.

The error behavior of `.remove(i)` and `.swap_remove(i)` is the same as for indexing a vector with `v[i]` syntax: If `i` is out of bounds, it's a programmer bug and the library functions panic. This is also called the *contract violation* clause in the error handling guidelines.

So the thought behind the library is that you only use `v[i]` or `v.remove(i)` if you know that `i` is in bounds, and you can indeed check that it is using `i < v.len()` or `v.get(i)` if you want.

There's another function that allows you to move an element out of a vector without possibility to panic, and that is `v.pop()` which removes the last item in the vector, returning `Option<T>` for a `Vec<T>`.

Comment: That's a good point about safety. Apologies for using the term incorrectly. With that said, is there a meaningful difference between `v.get` and `v.remove` regarding their behaviors?

Comment: `get` exists so that there is an option-returning way to index. (The main indexing facility is `v[i]`). There's no option-returning version of `remove`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`Vec::into_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator) to get an iterator that yields moved objects, and then use iterator APIs to select the item you want.

To move the first item out of a `Vec` (and throw away all others):

```
my_vec.into_iter().next()
    .expect("Expecting at least 1 item in vec")
```

Answer (score 5):

There's also [`vec::drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) which will give you an iterator over a range of values that were removed.  Now that I look at it though, this method would also panic on out-of-bounds access...