# How can I take an item from a Vec in Rust?

Tags: vector, collections, rust, move-semantics

I'm looking for a method that **consumes** a `Vec` and returns one element, without the overhead of restoring `Vec`'s invariants the way `remove` and `swap_remove` do:

```
fn take<T>(vec: Vec<T>, index: usize) -> Option<T>
```

However, I can't find such a method. Am I missing something? Is this actually unsafe or impossible?

This is a different question from [Built in *safe* way to move out of Vec<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489004/built-in-safe-way-to-move-out-of-vect)
There the goal was a `remove` method that didn't panic on out of bounds access and returned a `Result`. I'm looking for a method that consumes a `Vec` and returns one of the elements. None of the answers to the above question address my question.

Comment: Do you mean specifically `Option<T>` rather than `Option<&T>` that you can get from `vec.get(index)`, or did you miss that `.get` exists?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I specifically mean `Option<T>` like it says in my question. What I want is similar to `option.take()` if that makes sense?

Comment: Note: if you find yourself throwing `Vec` on a regular basis, you may want to see if you can avoid materializing them to start with. Not doing anything is always faster than doing something, no matter how efficient you are at doing it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can write your function like this:

```
fn take<T>(mut vec: Vec<T>, index: usize) -> Option<T> {
    if vec.get(index).is_none() {
        None
    } else {
        Some(vec.swap_remove(index))
    }
}
```

The code you *see* here (`get` and `swap_remove`) is guaranteed O(1).

*However*, kind of hidden, `vec` is dropped at the end of the function and this drop operation is likely not O(1), but O(n) (where n is `vec.len()`). If `T` implements `Drop`, then `drop()` is called for every element still inside the vector, meaning dropping the vector is guaranteed O(n). If `T` does not implement `Drop`, then the `Vec` only needs to deallocate the memory. The time complexity of the `dealloc` operation depends on the allocator and is not specified, so we cannot assume it is O(1).

---

To mention another solution using iterators:

```
fn take<T>(vec: Vec<T>, index: usize) -> Option<T> {
    vec.into_iter().nth(index)
}
```

While `Iterator::nth()` usually is a *linear time* operation, the iterator over a vector [overrides this method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.IntoIter.html#method.advance_by) to make it a O(1) operation. Of course, if `T` implements `Drop`, this again is an O(n) function as n elements need to be dropped.

Comment: Ah, this is a bit of an ugly solution, but I think it should work! I still think a `take` method on Vec would be great...

Comment: @Others Maybe you should open a RFC

Comment: How about changing `mut vec: Vec<T>` to `vec: &mut Vec<T>` in first solution?

Comment: @lukwol: Why? The OP explicitly asked something that consumes the vector.

Comment: I don't know what was the case when this answer was written, but as of today, `into_iter().nth()` _is_ O(1), unless the items implement `Drop` - but that is also true about the "`swap_remove()` then drop the `Vec`" approach.

Answer (score 8):

The reason `fn take<T>(vec: Vec<T>, index: usize) -> Option<T>` does not exist in the standard library is that it is not very useful in general. For example, supposing that you have a `Vec<String>` of length 10, it means throwing away 9 strings and only using 1. This seems wasteful.

In general, the standard library will try to provide an API that is useful in a maximum of scenarios, and in this instance it would be more logical to have a `fn take<T>(vec: &mut Vec<T>, index: usize) -> Option<T>`.

The only question is how to preserve the invariant, of course:

- it can be preserved by exchanging with the last element, which is what `Vec::swap_remove` does,
- it can be preserved by shifting the successor elements in, which is what `Vec::drain` does.

Those are very flexible, and can be adapted to fill more specific scenarios, such as yours.

---

Adapting `swap_remove`:

```
fn take<T>(mut vec: Vec<T>, index: usize) -> Option<T> {
    if index < vec.len() {
        Some(vec.swap_remove(index))
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Adapting `drain`:

```
fn take<T>(mut vec: Vec<T>, index: usize) -> Option<T> {
    if index < vec.len() {
        vec.drain(index..index+1).next()
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Noting that the former is more efficient: it's O(1).

---

> I'm looking for a method that consumes the `Vec` and returns one element, without the overhead of restoring `Vec`'s invariants the way `remove` and `swap_remove` do.

This reeks of premature micro-optimization to me.

First of all, note that it is necessary to destroy the elements of the vector; you can accomplish this in two ways:

1. `swap_remove`, then iterate over each element to destroy them,
2. Iterate over each element to destroy them, skipping the specific `index`.

It is not clear to me that the latter would be faster than the former; if anything it looks more complicated, with more branches (I advise two loops), which may throw off the predictor and may be less amenable to vectorization.

Secondly, before complaining about the overhead of restoring the `Vec`'s invariant, have you properly **profiled** the solution?

If we look at the `swap_remove` variant, there are 3 steps:

1. `swap_remove` (O(1)),
2. destroy each remaining element (O(N)),
3. free the backing memory.

Step 2 may be optimized out if the element has no `Drop` implementation, but otherwise I would be it's a toss whether (2) or (3) is dominating the cost.

**TL;DR**: I am afraid that you are fighting ghost issues, **profile** before trying to optimize.

Comment: I'm not necessarily only complaining about the overhead of restoring Vec's invariants (although the code I'm working with is in a tight inner loop, so speed really does matter to me), I also want to write code that follows what I mean. In this case, I really want to express the `take` operation, not a `remove` operation. Even if this was just a speed issue, I need an alternative to profile against anyway.

Comment: @Others: "Tight inner loop" and "dropping `Vec`" don't sound too good together. Once you've written the code, I encourage you to post it to Code Reviews or reddit and ask how to optimize it; hopefully there'll be a way to avoid a memory deallocation in your inner loop as those are costly.

Comment: Seeing as to how this question has 32k views as I'm writing this, `take` seems to be an needed for a lot of people