# get element from Vec that tell me could not move in rust

Tags: rust

I am learning to using rust to do some work. I am using this code to find element from Vec in rust:

```
let filtered_music:Vec<Music> = musics.iter()
            .filter(|item| item.source_id == fav.source_id)
            .collect();
```

the next step I want to put he element to another object:

```
let curr_music = &filtered_music[0];
let fav_resp = FavMusicResponse{
    id: (&fav.id.to_string()).parse().unwrap(),
    song_id: None,
    created_time: 0,
    updated_time: 0,
    user_id: 0,
    source_id: fav.source_id.to_string(),
    like_status: 0,
    source: 0,
    playlist_id: 0,
    play_count: 0,
    fetched_download_url: None,
    downloaded: None,
    music: curr_music
};
```

but the compiler tell me expected `Music`, found `&Music` , what should I do to fix it? This is my minimal example about this problem that could run in https://play.rust-lang.org/ to reproduce this situation:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let musics:Vec<Music> = Vec::new();
    let filtered_music:Vec<&Music> = musics.into_iter()
            .filter(|item| item.source_id == "1")
            .collect();
    let resp = MusicRes{
        music: filtered_music[0]
    };
}


pub struct Music {
    pub id: i64,
    pub name: String,
    pub artists: String,
    pub album_id: i64,
    pub publishtime: i64,
    pub status: i32,
    pub duration: i32,
    pub source_id: String,
    pub source: i32,
    pub created_time: i64,
    pub updated_time:i64,
    pub album: String,
    pub fetched_download_url: i32
}

pub struct MusicRes {
    pub music:Music
}
```

Comment: You may want to use `into_iter` instead of `iter`. This may help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57697614/1418750

Comment: `into_iter` still did not fix this problem. @Njuguna Mureithi the error keep the same.

Comment: Could you provide a more complete code sample esp one that can be debugged with https://play.rust-lang.org/

Comment: how to add a dependencies in `https://play.rust-lang.org/` @Njuguna Mureithi I did not found the cargo.toml

Comment: You cant, but playground includes the top 100 crates. eg `serde`. Nonetheless, you dont seem to need extra dependencies from your question.

Comment: I have made a minimal reproduce example.@Njuguna Mureithi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the major changes

```
fn take<T>(mut vec: Vec<T>, index: usize) -> Option<T> {
    if index < vec.len() {
        Some(vec.swap_remove(index))
    } else {
        None
    }
}
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    let musics: Vec<Music> = Vec::new();
    let filtered_music: Vec<Music> = musics
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|item| item.source_id == "1")
        .collect();
    let resp = MusicRes {
        music: take(filtered_music, 0).unwrap(),
    };
}
```

**Edit**

If you just want the first element of your music vector, consider using [`.next()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next) after filtering. This would avoid the `take` function.

My answer is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45814000/1418750)

Here is a working example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6d4137ccb7f737fa6261ea8c27bd012b